# How to get audioFocus on Current application?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager, android-mediasession

There are two different Media application with media browser service

1. One is system application and another one is normal application.
2. What happens here system application is taking audio focus when clicking the hardware button

here OnMediaButtonEvent taking intent to system application.

I need to set priority or focus on my currently running application

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered OnMediaButtonEvent callbacks in your application(Normal app)? If so, you can always request AudioFocus in your application, the System application will receive a focus loss event, and your application will be granted focus. (except during calls).
See this link for a detailed explanation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#audio-focus-8-0